# Lambda function not taken into account in tests

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, automated-tests

I am trying to deploy my first function on AWS Lambda that should store results on my S3 instance following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/data-driven-daily/automatic-data-scraping-using-aws-lambda-4f797bb46ce). To be sure I have the permission to write files to the S3 bucket I've created I  added the code below the commented one into the Function code section.

```
# import json

# def lambda_handler(event, context):
#     # TODO implement
#     return {
#         'statusCode': 200,
#         'body': json.dumps('Hello from fucking Lambda!')
#     }


import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.resource("s3") # pointer to AWS S3 service
    bucket_name = "my-own-bucket" # bucket for saving our data
    file_name = "HelloWorld.txt" # dummy file
    body = event['key1'] + ' ' +  event['key2'] + event['key3'] 
    # "Hello World!" from event input
    s3.Bucket(bucket_name).put_object(Key=file_name, Body=body) 
    # write object to bucket
    return f"Succeed! Find your new {file_name} file in {bucket_name} bucket ;)"
```

I used the template test event:

[image: Test event]

My code automatically saved, so I opened the S3 bucket again and verified that a HelloWorld.txt file existed. But it didn't. And the execution results were:

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"Hello from Lambda!\""
}

Request ID:
"93c1c61c-73cf-4308-9a88-0e8771612b8e"

Function logs:
START RequestId: 93c1c61c-73cf-4308-9a88-0e8771612b8e Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 93c1c61c-73cf-4308-9a88-0e8771612b8e
REPORT RequestId: 93c1c61c-73cf-4308-9a88-0e8771612b8e  Duration: 0.32 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 43 MB
```

Like if the commented code had still been taken into account.

Answer (score 2):

It could be due to following reasons:

1. You are invoking **old lambda version**, rather then your latest version.
2. You are **not deploying** your changes. In the new UI, there is no 'Save' button. Instead there is orange `Deploy` button.